# Navigation drawer doesn't display in Home page

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

- I am using a lollipop (api level 21).I had implemented the navigation
  drawer in my application.Everything was exactly fine.But I didn't see
  the navigation drawer at the end of output.
- I didn't get any error at runtime.My only problem is,I didn't know
  why I didn't get the navigation drawer at the end.
- Below I am posted the codes relevant to that.

**ChapterActivity.java:**

```
public class ChapterActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements OnItemClickListener {

private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerList;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_chapter);

        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_slidermenu);
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                R.drawable.ic_drawer,
                R.string.app_name, 

                R.string.app_name 
        ) {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                setTitle(mTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to show action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to hide action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        };  

        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
        initialize();
        listChapter.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    }

     private void initialize() {
     ......
     actionBar();
    }

     public void actionBar() {

        android.support.v7.app.ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color  
                .parseColor("#FFFFFF"))); 
        actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

        actionBar.setCustomView(mCustomView);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
    }

     public class getChapter extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {


        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            chapterList = DatabaseQueryHelper.getInstance().getChapters(); 


            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

            ac = new AdapterChapter(ChapterActivity.this, chapterList); // AdapterChapter

            listChapter.setAdapter(ac); 
            mDrawerList.setAdapter(ac);                 

        }

    }
}
```

**activity_chapter.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textviewHeading"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:fontFamily="fonts/Dosis.otf"
                android:text="@string/heading_chapter"
                android:textSize="25sp"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/listviewChapters"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_above="@+id/imageviewBanner"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textviewHeading"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp" >
            </ListView>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageviewBanner"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:src="@drawable/banner"
                android:visibility="invisible" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </FrameLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@color/list_background"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@color/list_divider"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**styles.xml:**

```
<resources>

    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat"></style>

    <!-- Application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
        <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
    </style>
</resources>
```

Finally I didn't seen the navigation drawer in home page.Anyone can help me with this.Where I did wrong.Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are using `android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle` . This class is deprecated and you should use `android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle`, which also has a different [constructor](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle.html#ActionBarDrawerToggle(android.app.Activity,%20android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout,%20android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar,%20int,%20int)).

```
public ActionBarDrawerToggle (Activity activity, DrawerLayout drawerLayout, int openDrawerContentDescRes, int closeDrawerContentDescRes)
public ActionBarDrawerToggle (Activity activity, DrawerLayout drawerLayout, Toolbar toolbar, int openDrawerContentDescRes, int closeDrawerContentDescRes)
```

The first links with you actual action bar. You just need to remove the reference to `ic_launcher`, and switch `v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle` to `v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle` in your imports.

The second ties with a `Toolbar` view, which I think you did not implement.

---

Second issue I see is a missing call when overriding `onDrawerOpened()` and `onDrawerClosed()` method. You should always call the super class:

```
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(view);
            // other stuff
        }
```

same goes for `onDrawerOpened()`.

Comment: Thnks for this suggestion.But it didn't work for me.let me know actionbardrawertoggle wouldn't work in api 21 because  it is deprecated?

Comment: You are extending `ActionBarActivity` from v7 so you shouldn't use the deprecated drawer toggle from v4. See my edited answer for a new suggestion.

Comment: very much thank you for your nice explanation and suggestion.Now I am clearly understood and solved my problem.